# SQL Azure S2 or P1 for B2B SaaS solution in asp.net

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, saas

I have a line of business solution for mostly B2B customer averaging 150+ requests per minute. It is hosted on a webrole on Azure. I was wondering if I should opt for Sql Azure S2, or Sql Azure P1. P1 is horribly expensive and before making the switch I wanted to know from others running Saas apps on Sql Azure as to which plan do they usually opt for.

Most of my queries Standard S2 take 250ms to execute, and I am not sure if this is too high or acceptable. Tx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Sirisha Chamarthi comments about the S3.

I've recently done some load testing and the S3 has been on par with the P1 in terms of load. 
Sometimes I've seen better performance of out the S3 which is really confusing me.

The P2 does give a slight improvement but a P3 really does perform well.

In my view the S3 is the best value for money.

Answer (score 1):

Switching between the different performance level is an on-line operation without a downtime.  You can move up and down from P* to S* anytime you need.  I would start with S2 and move to S3 or P1 if you need better response time or if you max out any of your resource allocations.

You also want to make sure to use the new V12 servers as they have more features for managing databases (online index build)

The only other thing is that Premium databases run on SSDs so you get very fast IOs in case you need that.

Comment: Tony, what I would want to know is is 250ms execution time for queries on azure acceptable. I only want to upgrade if this is below average.

Comment: That depends on the query size and what you or your users are happy with.  For example a query that calculates a sum on 10 million rows might take a lot longer than a query that calculates a sum on 1,000 rows so there is no such thing as average execution time for database workloads.  If your customers are happy with the performance then why upgrade?  if your customers want better performance and you think the cost is reasonable then you can upgrade.

Comment: FYI you can only change size 4 times per day. Also Online index build was on web and business too. That said V12 servers do perform better in my mind.